# How do I specify the number of axis points in matplotlib and how do I extract theese points?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a small script that creates a matplotlib graph with **2000** random points following a random walk.

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to change the number of points on the **y-axis** as well as how I can extract these values?

When I run the code below, I get **5** points on the **Y-axis** but I'm looking for a way to expand this to **20** points as well as creating an array or series with these values. Many thanks in advance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dims = 1
step_n = 2000
step_set = [-1, 0, 1]
origin = np.zeros((1,dims))
random.seed(30)
step_shape = (step_n,dims)
steps = np.random.choice(a=step_set, size=step_shape)
path = np.concatenate([origin, steps]).cumsum(0)
plt.plot(path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

dims = 1
step_n = 2000
step_set = [-1, 0, 1]
origin = np.zeros((1,dims))
random.seed(30)
step_shape = (step_n,dims)
steps = np.random.choice(a=step_set, size=step_shape)
path = np.concatenate([origin, steps]).cumsum(0)
#first variant 
plt.plot(path)
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=20)
plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=20)
```

You can use locator_params in order to specify the number of ticks. Of course you can retrieve these points. For this you must create a subplot with ax, and then you can get the y_ticks with get_yticks.

```
#second variant
# create subplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(20, 11))
img = ax.plot(path)
plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=20)
y_values = ax.get_yticks() # y_values is a numpy array with your y values
```